# exclude d.ts file from glob

Tags: javascript

How can i include all ts files, but not .d.ts files in glob :

```
glob(path.join(some_path, '**/**.{!d.ts,ts,js}'))
```

Answer (score 16):

This glob pattern matches all `.ts` files except `.d.ts` files :

```
**/!(*.d).ts
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still includes `.d.ts` files

Comment: @developarvin `glob('**/!(*.d).ts', (err, files) => console.log(files))`